# How can I write this objective function for LS-RTM?

Tags: equations

This is the equation I want to write:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
\text{minimize}\frac{1}{2}\| \textbf{M}_l^{-1} \textbf{J}\textbf{M}_r^{-1}
 \widehat{\delta\textbf{m}} - \textbf{M}_l^{-1} \delta \textbf{d} \|^2
```

Comment: Welcome. // Please EDIT your question to add code of your attempts. You‘ll get better answers sooner. Thanks

Comment: What is LSD-RTM?

Comment: @PeterWilson LS-RTM stands for Least-Squares Reverse Time Migration, a geophysics algorithm whose main goal is to obtain an image of the subsurface, used in gas & oil industry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Use `\mathbf`, not `\textbf`, for math-y material
- Create a dedicated macro, called `\norm`, rather than engage in what's essentially visual formatting by writing `\| ... \|`.
- Optional: Deemphasize the visual prominence of the `\frac{1}{2}` term by using `\tfrac` ("text-style frac") instead of `\frac`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert} % dedicated \norm macro

\begin{document}

\[
\min_{\widehat{\delta\mathbf{m}}}\ 
\tfrac{1}{2}
\norm{ \mathbf{M}_l^{-1} \mathbf{J} \mathbf{M}_r^{-1}
       \widehat{\delta\mathbf{m}} 
      -\mathbf{M}_l^{-1} \delta\mathbf{d} 
     }^2
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used `optidef` package, a `LaTeX` library for optimization problems.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{optidef}
\begin{document}
\begin{mini}<b>
{\scriptstyle{\widehat{\delta\mathbf{m}}} }{ \frac{1}{2}\| \mathbf{M}_l^{-1} \mathbf{J}\mathbf{M}_r^{-1}\widehat{\delta\mathbf{m}} - \mathbf{M}_{l}^{-1} \delta \mathbf{d}\|^2, }{}{}
\end{mini}
\end{document}
```

[image]